# Is this Boolean function monotone, linear and self-dual?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

I have a Boolean function, which looks like this:

$ f(x,y,z)= (x∨y∧\neg z)∨ y\rightarrow \neg(x\rightarrow z) $

I simplified it to this:

$ (\neg x ∧ \neg y )∨ (x ∧ \neg z)   $

The questions that I need to answer is whether this function is monotone, linear and self-dual. I don't quite remember how to do this and googling didn't help much. Do I need the truth table for that? Even if I make it, which arguments do I look at? All $ x,y,z, \neg x, \neg y, \neg z $ or only the ones that I have in the function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your definition of $f$ is ambiguous: it needs more parentheses.

Comment: I actually added the first parentheses myself. Maybe that was wrong:(  The second parentheses mean that it's the negation of x→z .

Comment: If the original was $$x\lor y\land\neg z\lor y\to\neg(x\to z)\,,$$ it’s ambiguous without information on which of $\lor$ and $\land$ has higher precedence for the author.